# Nest function over multiple dataframes

Tags: r, nested, nested-lists, tidyr

I have several dataframes with firm-advisor relationships, one for each year of interest.

For instance, the 2015 dataframe looks like this. Let's call it advisors2015 (then I have also advisors2014, advisors2013, advisors2012, and so on):

```
> advisors2015
       [,1]   [,2]                    [,3]           [,4]                        
colnam "Mark" "Company.name"          "Company.ID"   "Advisor.Name"              
row1   "1"    "VOLKSWAGEN AG"         "DE2070000543" "PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS"    
row2   " "    "VOLKSWAGEN AG"         "DE2070000543" "PWC DEUTSCHE REVISION"     
row3   " "    "VOLKSWAGEN AG"         "DE2070000543" "C&L TREUARBEIT REVISION"   
row4   "2"    "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC" "GB04366849"   "LLOYDS TSB REGISTRARS"     
row4   "2"    "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC" "GB04366849"   "LLOYDS TSB REGISTRARS"     
row5   " "    "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC" "GB04366849"   "PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS"
row6   " "    "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC" "GB04366849"   "KPMG ACCOUNTANTS NV"       
row7   " "    "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC" "GB04366849"   "ERNST & YOUNG"             
row8   "3"    "BP PLC"                "GB00102498"   "CAPITA ASSET SERVICES"
```

> And this is for 2014:

```
> advisors2014
         [,1]   [,2]                    [,3]           [,4]                        
colnam "Mark" "Company.name"          "Company.ID"   "Advisor.Name"              
row1   "1"    "VOLKSWAGEN AG"         "DE2070000543" "PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS"    
row2   " "    "VOLKSWAGEN AG"         "DE2070000543" "PWC DEUTSCHE REVISION"     
row3   " "    "VOLKSWAGEN AG"         "DE2070000543" "C&L TREUARBEIT REVISION"   
row4   "2"    "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC" "GB04366849"   "LLOYDS TSB REGISTRARS"     
row5   " "    "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC" "GB04366849"   "PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS"
row6   "3"    "BP PLC"                "GB00102498"   "CAPITA ASSET SERVICES"     
row7   "4"    "COCACOLA"              "GB111222333"  " "
```

As you can see, each company may have one ore more advisors. Of course they may also change over time: this year (that means in this dataframe) VOLKSWAGEN has 3 advisors but next year it may have just one, or substitute some of them with some others.

In order to keep track of all these changes, I would like to have a dataframe where for each company/year observation I save the list of advisors.

I know that we can do this using the `nest` function, but as far as I understand it is for creating lists from columns in the **same dataframe**, while **I have multiple dataframes**, say 10, like the ones above.

Could anyone help me to manage this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: You could split according to company:advisor  combination and construct whatever result you want from that. If you provide a reproducible example I can show you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. What do you mean reproducible example? I am not very practical of this website.

Comment: In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a single data frame in which the columns are `year`, `Company.name` and a column containing a list each of whose elements is a data frame containing the rows for that year and Company.name then:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

ls(pattern = "^advisors\\d{4}$", envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
  mget(envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
  map_dfr(as.data.frame.matrix, .id = "year") %>%
  mutate(year = sub("advisors", "", year) %>% as.numeric) %>%
  nest(-c(year, Company.name))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   year Company.name          data                
  <dbl> <fct>                 <list>              
1 2015. VOLKSWAGEN AG         <data.frame [3 x 3]>
2 2015. ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC <data.frame [4 x 3]>
3 2015. BP PLC                <data.frame [1 x 3]>
4 2016. VOLKSWAGEN AG         <data.frame [3 x 3]>
5 2016. ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC <data.frame [4 x 3]>
6 2016. BP PLC                <data.frame [1 x 3]>
```

or if you just want a long form data frame then omit the `nest` line.

### Note

We assume the input is:

```
advisors2015 <- 
structure(list(Mark = c(1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 3L), 
Company.name = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("BP PLC", "ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC", 
"VOLKSWAGEN AG"), class = "factor"), Company.ID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("DE2070000543", "GB00102498", 
"GB04366849"), class = "factor"), Advisor.Name = structure(c(6L, 
8L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("C&L TREUARBEIT REVISION", 
"CAPITA ASSET SERVICES", "ERNST & YOUNG", "KPMG ACCOUNTANTS NV", 
"LLOYDS TSB REGISTRARS", "PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS", "PRICEWATERHOUSECOOPERS LLP", 
"PWC DEUTSCHE REVISION"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

advisors2015 <- advisors2016 <- as.table(as.matrix(advisors2015))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Well, when i run your command it returns me the error "Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 2 must be length 36, not 4". However the structure of the data is provided above now.

Comment: If you paste the input from the Note into R and then paste the code you will see that there is no error.  If your own data gives an error then there is some difference that you haven't told us about.  If the difference is that your data is matrices then convert them to data frames first.

Comment: Ok, they should be tibbles.

Comment: Have changed Note and code to make input tables.  The output is a data frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I try to apply it to my data.

Comment: I did it. May you suggest me some references about how to deal with data with lists as variables?

Comment: `nest` is part of tidyr package and `map_dfr` is in purrr so look at the documentation for those.